# GCM ERROR(Permission Error)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

I am working on GCM getting. My app is not even launching and getting crahsed. following error

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- FOR GCM START1 -->
<permission
    android:name="com.ama.gcmdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.ama.gcmdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- FOR GCM END1 -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ama.gcmdemo.MainActivityActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
           <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.ama.gcmdemo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name=".DialogService" />
</application>
```

And getting following error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ama.gcmdemo/com.ama.gcmdemo.MainActivityActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.ama.gcmdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Main activity is direct under com.ama.gcmdemo package.

Please suggest where is the fault

Comment: Have you added the GCM library in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this permissions in manifest file

```
  <permission
    android:name="<package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="<package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

in place of package-name give your package name

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Just change the below line inside your receiver,

```
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
```

to,

```
android:name="com.ama.gcmdemo.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
```

And make sure that you have the `GCMBroadcastReceiver.java` inside your package. Bcs, you should have the receiver inside your package to receive the GCM messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your recevier with the GCM package name not your application package name as below:

> ```
>      <receiver
>     android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver">
> ```

**Not**

> ```
>    <receiver
>         android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
> ```